# CSS Grid - Adjusting to content within div

Tags: css, css-grid, styled-components

I'm about to implement tags on our website, and we want to add them dynamically from our CMS. All tags renders on page and we are able to use the tags, though we would like the div's to auto adjust to the text length.

See an example of the end goal:

[image]

Right now the tags are having full width of the container like the image below:

[image]

Using CSS grid and styled-components, how can we accomplish auto adjusting width of div's?

This is how the code is now:

```js
import React from "react"
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby"
import styled from "styled-components"
import { H3, MediumText } from "../styles/TextStyles"

export default function CategorySection() {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query categoryQuery {
      allGraphCmsCategory {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            title
            slug
            description
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

   return (
    <Wrapper>
      <ContentWrapper>
        <TextWrapper>
          <Title>Browse by Categories</Title>
          <Description>
            Use the category tags to narrow down what you are looking for.
          </Description>
        </TextWrapper>
        <CategoryWrapper>
          {data.allGraphCmsCategory.edges.map(tags => {
            return (
              <Categories key={tags.node.id}>{tags.node.title}</Categories>
            )
          })}
        </CategoryWrapper>
      </ContentWrapper>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}

const Wrapper = styled.div``

const ContentWrapper = styled.div``

const TextWrapper = styled.div``

const Title = styled(H3)``

const Description = styled(MediumText)``

const CategoryWrapper = styled.div``

const Categories = styled.div``
```

Comment: what you are describing is not a grid

Comment: I'm not describing anything. I'm asking how to accomplish it in a grid. Imagine when you have 20 tags, those will have to go inside a grid of some sort to be responsive.

Comment: *Imagine when you have 20 tags, those will have to go inside a grid of some sort to be responsive.* <-- this is what you are *describing* and it's not a grid. Use inline-block, float or flexbox

Comment: I was able to do it using CSS grid. Thanks for the advice though. I will look into your suggestions to see if it is even better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with

```
grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
```

It will do the trick

Comment: It will still use the full width of the parent container.

Comment: I ended up with a combination of your suggestion and an outer div with CSS grid. Thanks for the help :)